# I need help I keep getting this error I am new to c

Tags: c

I keep getting the same error when I try to compile it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char name[25];
    int age;

    printf("\nwhat is your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("what is your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("\nyour name is %s", name);
    printf("\nand your age is %d", age);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us what the error is?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The shown code compiles without an error. Gives a warning though.

Comment: <O/T> suggest you put your new lines at the _end_ of your `printf` strings, like `printf("your name is %s\n", name);`. The reason being, `printf` is line-buffered, meaning that it flushes to `stdout` (prints) when it encounters a newline `'\n'`. With newlines at the beginning, you may eventually find yourself in certain situations scratching your head because your line didn't print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is the "error" you are receiving:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:9:9: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[25]' [-Wformat=]
 scanf("%s", &name);
```

You should try to read and understand it, as compiler warnings usually are quite clear. This one tells you that the `%s` in the line `scanf("%s", &name);` expects a `char *`, that is, a pointer to a char, whereas you have supplied a `char (*)[25]` which is a pointer to an array of 25 chars.

Basically, the argument `&name` has the wrong type. The name of the array, in this case the `name` is a pointer to the first element of the array, and you should not put an ampersand (&) (the address of ...) operator when giving it as an argument to `scanf`.

The correct call would be: `scanf("%s", name);`.

I also strongly suggest you to avoid using `scanf` as a user-interface function. See [this](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).